# C# Universal App: add scrollbar to textblock / textblock

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am new to C# and Universal App. Unfortunately I have not found a way to add a scrollbar to a textblock / textbox.
Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is quick solution. Put `TextBox` inside `ScrollViewer`.

```
<ScrollViewer Height="Auto">
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Text="example" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response!

Comment: do you occassionally know how to automatically scroll to the bottom of the textbox after inserting a new text? I have read that it had worked with the .append method. Unfortunately this method does not exist within universal apps.